# Releasing a modular maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, modularity

I'm using maven from a few time, and I used release plugin only one time. Now I'm working on a modular project the look like to this:

[image]

Now I'm reading some things about the release of a modular project and I saw that some people use a same version for all modules, but in this case how Can i manage upgrade and bug fixing on the modules. Summarizing I'm really confused on this topic and I want to ask you some suggestion on how to begin to address this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also have a similar structure of modules. Each in its **own** maven project.
Each module has its own life-cycle and its own version.
Using your module names -

You want to upgrade the **services** module

- You release a new version of **services**
- You update the **rest**, **admin-webapp** and **webapp** with the **services** new version
- You build them and release them

This methodology requires that you manage the dependencies properly.
We try to keep it simple, but with many modules, you can get in to a dependency hell.

Another option is to keep all modules in a single, multi-module maven project

- Where you have a single version for all modules (parent pom)
- You build all the project, releasing all modules with each new change

Makes an easy life of managing dependencies, but many unneeded releases.

I think both options are valid. You have to see what your team will feel easy to manage and scale over time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: From my point of view the multi-module setup has great advantages cause all the artifacts have the same version which means you can use them together and don't need to think about if they are working together or better if they have been tested in the particular combination which i'm currently using.

Comment: as I mentioned, there are several approaches to this need. I find our way to be more scalable and instead of building the whole project we literally build only the modules that have changed. just try and keep it simple and find what's best for your development team.